# Adding custom variables to paypal IPN from a cURL payment

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, paypal

My question : Setting up paypal variables that will be returned on the IPN.

So background:
I'm working with CodeIgniter and I'm using a pre-made online library I found to deal with the whole paypal thing. The library does the heavy lifting and it works great.
[This is the library I'm using][1]

From what i understand, the library sends a cURL request using XML format to paypal with all the needed information, basically as depicted in paypal itself [here][2]

This library is poorly documented and I have no idea how to take the next step.

The next step being, Add data to the cURL request that will show up on the IPN.

To be exact; I'll find a way to add the data, I'm more interested in how this should look at the end.

This is a classic transaction part of the cURL request(from what i gathered):

```
 "transactions":[
    {
      "amount":{
        "total":"7.47",
        "currency":"USD"
      }
    }
  ]
```

I'm wondering how should the information I need look like, for instance if i wanted to pass userID, would it be something along the lines of

```
"userID":"4",
```

and should it be nested in some other argument?

If any other code is needed i'll gladly post it, I did search for the topic extensively and all the answers i found were related to forms and hidden fields, Not the case for me.(As stated paypal is being provoked through a PHP function that uses cURL).

Thanks in advance!

edit:

Hello! Thanks for your reply and thanks alot for this awesome lib :)
I'm using the Adaptive_payments controller with the pay method.

I've just realized the invoiceID indeed gets returned which fits great.
I'm missing something in your answer though, Many fields are not being returned by the IPN, including customerID(which is what I tried using, I just assumed nothing gets returned).

Here's my return arguements as captured by the IPN:

```
    cmd=_notify-validate
    &transaction_subject=
    &payment_date=12%3A02%3A40+Jan+29%2C+2014+PST
    &txn_type=web_accept
    &last_name=patrick
    &residence_country=US
    &item_name=
    &payment_gross=50.00
    &mc_currency=USD
    &business=test@example.com //not the actual email
    &payment_type=instant
    &protection_eligibility=Ineligible
    &verify_sign=ASsSVovq77sBsVg2xPiCnEG3N9AIAD1pW3tgoSX59hTmz9AA9lT6AH0E
    &payer_status=verified
    &test_ipn=1
    &tax=0.00
    &payer_email=patrick.buyer%40gmail.com
    &txn_id=69J264685H5924531&quantity=0
    &receiver_email=test@example.com //not the actual email
    &first_name=patrick
    &payer_id=5MLPF23854T8Q
    &receiver_id=F5K3CSR99E9WA
    &item_number=
    &payment_status=Completed
    &payment_fee=1.75
    &mc_fee=1.75
    &mc_gross=50.00
    &custom=
    &charset=windows-1252
    &notify_version=3.7
    &ipn_track_id=50879f4bb9d2
```

It seems not all of the controller's controls are being returned by the IPN.
Invoice will fit me perfectly and I'll mark as answered.
Thanks alot for your time and effort.

Edit 2 : 
$PayPalResult['RawResponse'] doesn't exist for some reason, I did a var_dump of $PayPalResult (in the adaptive_payment controller, right before i'm redirecting to paypal).

```
array(10) {
  ["Errors"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["Ack"]=>
  string(7) "Success"
  ["Build"]=>
  string(7) "7935900"
  ["CorrelationID"]=>
  string(13) "8c2afcee2d74b"
  ["Timestamp"]=>
  string(29) "2014-01-31T02:37:38.806-08:00"
  ["PayKey"]=>
  string(20) "AP-1WW538504G900525L"
  ["PaymentExecStatus"]=>
  string(7) "CREATED"
  ["RedirectURL"]=>
  string(81) "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-1WW538504G900525L"
  ["XMLRequest"]=>
  string(1439) "ReturnAllen_USPAYhttp://httpexample.no-ip.biz/ROOT/index.php/userControllers/regularuserActions/viewShoppingCartAPP-80W284485P519543T109.67.55.127USDBALANCECREDITCARDhttp://httpexample.no-ip.biz/root/index.php/main/IPNIPN100XXXXXXX@gmail.com5SERVICEfalsehttp://httpexample.no-ip.biz/ROOT/index.php/userControllers/regularuserActions/paypalSuccess"
  ["XMLResponse"]=>
  string(373) "2014-01-31T02:37:38.806-08:00Success8c2afcee2d74b7935900AP-1WW538504G900525LCREATED"
}
```

So in short, my IPN class is being called, but it can't find any information to deal with(i've confirmed this with a log, the debug shows the class is called but no $_POST data exists).

Edit 3 :

XML request is generated fine, the specific attribute which i tested was myownID - that appears in the request.

for some reason though no $_POST information is being sent back.
this line in the IPN method :

$this->_log ( 'debug - IPN export for application is ' . var_export ( $_POST ) );

shows like this on my logs : 
 debug - IPN export for application is

[XMLRequest] => `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><PayRequest xmlns="http://svcs.paypal.com/types/ap"><requestEnvelope xmlns=""><detailLevel>ReturnAll</detailLevel><errorLanguage>en_US</errorLanguage></requestEnvelope><actionType xmlns="">PAY</actionType><cancelUrl xmlns="">http://httpexample.no-ip.biz/ROOT/index.php/userControllers/regularuserActions/viewShoppingCart</cancelUrl><clientDetails xmlns=""><applicationId xmlns="">APP-80W284485P519543T</applicationId><customerId xmlns="">myownID</customerId><geoLocation xmlns="">Israel</geoLocation><ipAddress xmlns="">109.67.55.127</ipAddress></clientDetails><currencyCode xmlns="">ILS</currencyCode><fundingConstraint xmlns=""><allowedFundingType xmlns=""><fundingTypeInfo xmlns=""><fundingType xmlns="">BALANCE</fundingType></fundingTypeInfo><fundingTypeInfo xmlns=""><fundingType xmlns="">CREDITCARD</fundingType></fundingTypeInfo></allowedFundingType></fundingConstraint><ipnNotificationUrl xmlns="">http://httpexample.no-ip.biz/root/index.php/main/IPN</ipnNotificationUrl><receiverList xmlns=""><receiver xmlns=""><amount xmlns="">25</amount><email xmlns="">XXXXXX@gmail.com</email><invoiceId xmlns="">5</invoiceId><paymentType xmlns="">SERVICE</paymentType><primary xmlns="">false</primary></receiver></receiverList><sender><useCredentials xmlns=""></useCredentials></sender><account xmlns=""><phone xmlns=""></phone></account><returnUrl xmlns="">http://httpexample.no-ip.biz/ROOT/index.php/userControllers/regularuserActions/paypalSuccess</returnUrl></PayRequest>`

edit : latest IPN attributes as recieved from the application IPN into my IPN method.

```
cmd=_notify-validate&
transaction=
&payment_request_date=Sun+Feb+02+08%3A25%3A52+PST+2014
&return_url=http%3A%2F%2Fhttpexample.no-ip.biz%2FROOT%2Findex.php%2FuserControllers%2FregularuserActions%2FpaypalSuccess
&fees_payer=EACHRECEIVER
&ipn_notification_url=http%3A%2F%2Fhttpexample.no-ip.biz%2Froot%2Findex.php%2Fpaypal%2Fpaypal_ipn%2Frunagain
&sender_email=patrick.buyer%40gmail.com
&verify_sign=AFcWxV21C7fd0v3bYYYRCpSSRl31AwGY-gIhQZM2WI9Ae63J.CxI7j4y
&test_ipn=1
&cancel_url=http%3A%2F%2Fhttpexample.no-ip.biz%2FROOT%2Findex.php%2FuserControllers%2FregularuserActions%2FviewShoppingCart
&pay_key=AP-6RR41041VH869594S
&action_type=PAY
&transaction_type=Adaptive+Payment+PAY
&status=COMPLETED
&log_default_shipping_address_in_transaction=false
&charset=windows-1252
&notify_version=UNVERSIONED
&reverse_all_parallel_payments_on_error=false
```

Comment: Keep in mind that with Adaptive Payments there is an application specific IPN and a merchant specific IPN.  Your application would receive one to the IPN URL you specify in the API request.  I believe that one would containt the customer ID.  The merchant (seller account) would also receive an IPN with transaction specific data if they h ad IPN configured in their own Paypal account.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, So does that mean that I should be getting two distinct  sets of IPNs? One for the merchent account and one for the application itself?

That makes sense I guess.
I'm guessing I would require two different URL's for IPN handeling?

Comment: Yes, the API would have the URL for the application specific IPN, and then your PayPal profile would have where the seller account IPN would go.

Comment: I can't seem to get the application IPN to work, But I don't want to bother you with it, I'll be happy if you could provide any documentation on the matter, For now the invoice works perfectly(even though it's a bit strange passing a userID attribute through the invoice :) )

Comment: Let me see a sample of the XML request that's getting generated.  It comes back in the result as $PayPalResult['RawResponse']

Comment: i edited the main question

Comment: Sorry, I gave you the wrong name.  It's XMLRequest and XMLResponse. When you see that result dump out on screen, do a view page source, and then you can see the actual XML for both the request and the response.  That's really what I need to see.

Comment: Edited once more, Becoming a wall of text :)

Comment: When I browse http://httpexample.no-ip.biz/root/index.php/main/IPN directly I'm getting an error.  The IPN simulator said it was successful, though, although I can't see anything about whether it actually processed correctly or not.  Have you checked your web logs to see if that URL is getting hit after running the Pay request?

Comment: Hey there, That URL was undergoing some minor work :)

the current URL is :
http://httpexample.no-ip.biz/root/index.php/paypal/paypal_ipn/runagain

(that's the IPN URL and that's the current IPN address).

I'm updating the question with a fresh attribute list send back to paypal to confirm the transaction, those are the attributes that i have recieved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm the developer of that library and I'd be happy to help.  The JSON stuff you posted refers to PayPal's new REST API, though, which is not what my library uses.  It uses the [classic API's](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/), which are still more mature and less limiting than the REST API is today.

Which API are you working with in particular?  The library comes with controllers that are already setup and include all the parameters possible in the request.  Any data included with the request would come back in IPN as well.

If you have custom fields that you need to include then you need to use the CUSTOM parameter when available, or another option would be to save data in your DB and then pass the record ID in CUSTOM or INVNUM.  That way the ID would come back in IPN and you could pull all your details back out of your DB.

If you're working with the Pay API you can include the InvoiceID parameter in the $Receiver data, which is already included in the controller method for Pay().  Pay_with_options() combines both Pay and SetPaymentOptions API's, which provides more parameters including a CustomID that could be used and would also come back in the IPN.

I can help you more if you provide more detail about exactly which API's you're using.

Comment: Edited in response. Thanks